# Mysql Group by function

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
Id customer email        timestamp             store_id
1    1      abc@xx.com   2014-04-11 17:06:21   5416
2    0      xyz@xy.com   2014-04-11 15:05:23   5416
3    1      abc@xx.com   2014-04-11 17:55:34   5416
4    2      bca@bc.com   2014-04-11 17:55:34   5416
```

and my query is:

```
SELECT *, count(*) as total FROM `tybo_orders` 
WHERE timestamp IN (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM `tybo_orders`
GROUP BY email) AND store_id='5416' GROUP BY email
```

A value of 0 in the `customer` column means guest and more than 0 means customer id. I want to group by `email` if `customer` is 0 else group by `customer`. How is it possible?

Comment: use case statements to apply condtions

Comment: What is the output that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This

```
SELECT *, count(*) as total 
FROM `tybo_orders` 
WHERE timestamp IN (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM `tybo_orders` GROUP BY email) 
AND 
store_id='5416' 
GROUP BY 
case when customer=0 then customer else email end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
SELECT *, count(*) as total 
FROM `tybo_orders` 
WHERE timestamp IN (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM `tybo_orders` GROUP BY email) 
AND 
store_id='5416' 
GROUP BY 
IF(customer=0,email,customer)
```